# How to create conditional join in Ecto Query?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

i have 2 models - User and ApiKey (user has_many api_keys) and i'm trying to create conditional join. I mean i'd like to load with single query User with his active ApiKeys. My current code looks like

```
query = from u in User, 
        join: a in assoc(u, :api_keys), 
        where: u.email == ^email,
        preload: [api_keys: a]
user = Repo.one(query)
Repo.preload user, api_keys: (from a in ApiKey, where: a.is_active == true)
```

But unfortunately as i see - preload method cannot change collection of api_keys when data is already preloaded.

Could you please show me good example - how to preload only "active" api_keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/962) on Ecto may be relevant for you.

Currently you have two options:

Use `Enum.map` after fetching using `join` and `select`:

```
query = from u in User, 
        join: a in assoc(u, :api_keys), 
        where: u.email == ^email,
        where: a.is_active == true,
        select: {u, a}
user = Repo.one(query) |> Enum.map(fn ({u, a}) -> %{u | api_keys: a} end)
```

Use a query as an argument to [Ecto.Query.preload/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3):

```
api_key_query = from a in ApiKey, where: a.is_active == true
query = from u in User, 
        join: a in assoc(u, :api_keys), 
        where: u.email == ^email,
        preload: [api_keys: ^api_key_query]
user = Repo.one(query)
```

Comment: in second option you wrote app will perform 2 db requests instead of one :(

Comment: @AlexeyPoimtsev Performing two or more queries is always the case when using preload. However, preloading can often perform better than using joins. Please read the "Querying Associations" section of http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/  - " This is often the most efficient way of loading associations from the database (even if two queries are performed) because we need to receive and parse only POSTS + COMMENTS results."

Comment: @Gazler is it possible to join the same association twice in Ecto, each time with a different condition? I get an error `cannot preload `prices` as it has been supplied more than once with different queries` so I'm assuming it's a no. But how to get around that?